# Can I change the class of a div max-width section?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove a class from a div section, in @media(max-width:767px) section in css file. 
Shortly, I want to remove the offset from "div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3" when the screen becomes narrower than 767px.

Is that possible to do just with css edit? I don't want to use JavaScript for that, if I don't have to.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With media queries you can.

Comment: Please use the `twitter-bootstrap` tag. The `bootstrap` tag means something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use css. You can just use bootstrap's offset class for that breakpoint.

```
 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0">
```

Comment: I forgot about that. Thank you.